# SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault) при вызове функции printf

Tags: ассемблер, printf, nasm, x86-64

Возникла такая проблема: при вызове *printf*  вылетает *SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault)*. Вот код на *nasm*:

```
BITS 64
extern printf

section .data
    x         dd     4
    format    db     ' %2d', 0     
section .text
global main
main:
    push QWORD [x]
    push format
    call printf

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Система у вас 64-битная, параметры передаются не через стек, а через регистры.

```
BITS 64
extern printf

section .data
x       dd     4
format  db     ' %2d', 0

section .text

global main

main:
  mov rdi, format
  mov rsi, [x]
  mov rax, 0
  call printf

  ret
```

Поищите в гугле по запросу "x86-64 call convention". Вкратце есть, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) в разделе "x86-64 Linux & DragonFly BSD System Call convention".